# Filtering stops working after multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want users to be able to filter data by a few different properties. The application works fine when you:

1. Only filter by the datetimes.
2. Only filter by all the other properties, excluding the datetimes
3. Or, filtering by one string property and one of the datetimes

For example, let's say I want to filter by type, branch and a datetime ascending, the parameters show in the URL but, the list shows all the data entries. But, if I just filter by type and datetime, type, branch and search or just datetime, the list filters correctly.

```
**Controller**
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string requestType, string requestBranch,string subDateSort,string installDateSort, string searchCustomer, int page = 1)
        {

            IQueryable<string> typeQuery = from t in db.imperialWebRequests
                                           select t.type;
            IQueryable<string> branchQuery = from b in db.imperialWebRequests
                                           select b.branchSite;
          

            List<SelectListItem> SubDateSort = new List<SelectListItem>()
                {
                    new SelectListItem() {Text="--Asc Or Desc--", Value=""},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text="Sub Date Ascending", Value="sub_date_asc"},
                    new SelectListItem() { Text="Sub Date Descending", Value="sub_date_desc"},
                };

                ViewBag.SubDateList = SubDateSort;

            List<SelectListItem> InstallDateSort = new List<SelectListItem>()
                {
                    new SelectListItem() {Text="--Asc Or Desc--", Value=""},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text="Install Date Ascending", Value="install_date_asc"},
                    new SelectListItem() { Text="Install Date Descending", Value="install_date_desc"},
                };

            ViewBag.InstallDateList = InstallDateSort;

            ViewBag.TypeParam = requestType;
            ViewBag.BranchParam = requestBranch;
            ViewBag.SearchParam = searchCustomer;
            ViewBag.InstallDateParam = installDateSort;
            ViewBag.SubDateParam = subDateSort;
           
            var webRequests = from wr in db.imperialWebRequests
                           select wr;


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestType))
            {
                webRequests = webRequests.Where(wr => wr.type == requestType);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBranch))
            {
                webRequests = webRequests.Where(wr => wr.branchSite == requestBranch);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCustomer))
            {
                webRequests = webRequests.Where(wr => wr.shiftsTextInput.Contains(searchCustomer));
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subDateSort))
            {
                switch (subDateSort)
                {
                    case "sub_date_asc":
                        webRequests = webRequests.OrderBy(di => di.dateInserted);
                        break;
                    case "sub_date_desc":
                        webRequests = webRequests.OrderByDescending(di => di.dateInserted);
                        break;

                }
            }
            
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(installDateSort))
            {
                switch (installDateSort)
                {
                    case "install_date_asc":
                        webRequests = webRequests.OrderBy(dp => dp.datepicker);
                        break;
                    case "install_date_desc":
                        webRequests = webRequests.OrderByDescending(dp => dp.datepicker);
                        break;

                }
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestType) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBranch) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCustomer) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(subDateSort) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(installDateSort))
            {
                webRequests = webRequests.OrderBy(di => di.dateInserted);

            }




            var requestVM = new ImperialFilterVM
            {
                RequestPerPage = 5,
                ImperialWebRequests = webRequests,
                CurrentPage = page
            };

            requestVM.types = new SelectList(await typeQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync());
            requestVM.branches = new SelectList(await branchQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync());
            


            requestVM.ImperialWebRequests = await webRequests.ToListAsync();

            return View(requestVM);
        }
```

```
**View Model**
 public class ImperialFilterVM
    {
        public imperialWebRequest ImperialWebRequest { get; set; }
        public List<imperialWebRequest> imperialWebRequestList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> types;
        public string requestType { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> branches { get; set; }
        public string requestBranch { get; set; }
        public string subDateSort { get; set; }
        public string installDateSort { get; set; }
        public string searchCustomer { get; set; }

       


        public IEnumerable<imperialWebRequest> ImperialWebRequests { get; set; }
        public int RequestPerPage { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

        public int PageCount()
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(ImperialWebRequests.Count() / (double)RequestPerPage));
        }
        public IEnumerable<imperialWebRequest> PaginatedWebRequests()
        {
            int start = (CurrentPage - 1) * RequestPerPage;
            return ImperialWebRequests.Skip(start).Take(RequestPerPage);
        }


    }
```

```
**Route Config**
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "IWRControllerIndex",
               url: "imperialWebRequests/Index/{id}/{requestType}/{requestBranch}/{subDateSort}/{installDateSort}/{searchCustomer}",
               defaults: new { controller = "imperialWebRequests", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, requestType = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                   requestBranch = UrlParameter.Optional,subDateSort = UrlParameter.Optional,installDateSort = UrlParameter.Optional,searchCustomer = UrlParameter.Optional
               }
           );
        }
    }
```

```
**Index**
@model  imperialWebInstallRequestsCRUD.Models.ImperialFilterVM


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Recent";

}



<h2>Recent Request Install/Change Outs</h2>


<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImperialWebRequest.type)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImperialWebRequest.salesPerson)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImperialWebRequest.branchSite)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImperialWebRequest.shiftsTextInput)
                </th>
                
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImperialWebRequest.ExisitingCustomerCheckBox)
                </th>
               
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImperialWebRequest.datepicker)
                </th>
                
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImperialWebRequest.dateInserted)

            </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model.PaginatedWebRequests())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.type)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.salesPerson)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.branchSite)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shiftsTextInput)
                    </td>
                   
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExisitingCustomerCheckBox)
                    </td>
                   
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.datepicker)
                    </td>
                   
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dateInserted)

                </td>
                    <td>
                       
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.requestId }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.requestId })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>

        <ul class="pagination">
            @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.PageCount(); i++)
            {
            <li class="@(i == Model.CurrentPage ? "page-item active" : "page-item")">
                <a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", new { page = i, requestType = ViewBag.TypeParam, 
                                              requestBranch = ViewBag.BranchParam, subDateSort = ViewBag.SubDateParam,
                                               installDateSort = ViewBag.InstallDateParam, searchCustomer = ViewBag.SearchParam})">@i</a>
            </li>

            }
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-3">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "imperialWebRequests", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.requestType, "Request Type")
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.requestType, Model.types, "Select A Type", new { @class = "form-control form-control-lg" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.requestType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.requestBranch, "Request Branch")
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.requestBranch, Model.branches, "Select A Branch", new { @class = "form-control form-control-lg" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.requestBranch, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Submitted Date")
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.subDateSort, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SubDateList,new { @class = "form-control form-control-lg" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Install Date")
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.installDateSort, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.InstallDateList, new { @class = "form-control form-control-lg" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.searchCustomer, new { placeholder = "Enter A Customer's Name", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
            <button type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            <span>|</span>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've removed your ASP.NET Core tag as it was the odd one out amongst your .NET Framework tags.

Comment: Hint - some of your `else if` should be `if`. Debug through the code, line by line, and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @mjwills I'll check that out now, thank you for the tip.

Comment: @mjwills Still getting the same results as before

Comment: That isn't possible. `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestType))
            {
                webRequests = webRequests.Where(wr => wr.type == requestType);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBranch))
            {
                webRequests = webRequests.Where(wr => wr.branchSite == requestBranch);
            }` will clearly only apply _only_ of those filters. If you switch the `else if` to `if` then behaviour _will change_.

Comment: @mjwills Even if I switch all of the else if to if statements, the behavior stays the same. I can filter something like requestType and by a datetime property but if I try to filter it by requestType, requestBranch and a datetime property, the filtering breaks.

Comment: I can't comment on code that I can't see.